# USING Fragments in ANDROID to get TAB feature

Tags: android, android-fragments

### Implementing Tab Feature using Radio Button with Fragments

**I have got this functionality using tabhost ... regular tabs .**

[image]

---

- **Is it possible to get this using Fragments as shown in the figure**

***If so how ?***

- **An example would be helpful**

Comment: How did such a mediocre question get so many upvotes so fast? Well, sockpuppets.

Comment: You should take a look at this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: duplicate question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330811/using-fragments-in-android-for-tab-feature-representation). Are you maintaining two accounts by any chance !!??

Comment: its a duplicate, i cant flag it :(

Comment: @Unicorn check out my answer and try to implement accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Try out as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // radiobutton to change Fragment
        RadioButton tab1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
        RadioButton tab2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioMale);

        RadioGroup tab_group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        // radioGroupListener
        tab_group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioFemale:
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm.beginTransaction();
                    Fragment m_fragSet = new GamesFragment();
                    ft1.replace(R.id.frameLayout2, m_fragSet);
                    ft1.commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.radioMale:
                                    FragmentManager fmg = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ftr = fmg.beginTransaction();
                Fragment m_frag = new MoviesFragment();
                ftr.replace(R.id.frameLayout2, m_frag);
                ftr.commit();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Layout **activity_main**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioSex"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="radiobutton1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="radiobutton2" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/passenger"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```